# Como pasar datos de componente a otros componentes

Tags: javascript, json, angular

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en angular, en el cual cargo un archivo en formatos json y lo muestro en una tabla. Yo hasta ahora tengo tres componentes que son:

- UploadComponent
- TableComponent
- TableDetalleComponent

Mi duda es como desde UploadComponent puedo enviar los datos a TableComponent y TableDetalleComponent, este es mi codigo:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TableComponent } from '../table/table.component';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {tableInf} from './upload.model';
import {UploadService} from '../services/upload.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})



export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

displayedColumns: string[] = ['noMaquina', 'cantidadDatos','promedioTCH', 'tiempoTrabajo', 'promedioVelocidad', 'noDescargas' ];
fileText;
datos;
datosServices;
nombre:any="";
mee=this;

fileUpload(event) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsText(event.srcElement.files[0]);
   var me = this;
   reader.onload = function () {
     me.fileText = reader.result;
     var json = me.fileText;
     me.datos = JSON.parse(json)
     me.nombre=me.datos;
   }
   this.pruebas();
 }

 public pruebas(){
   alert("Mis datos: " + this.nombre.id);
   debugger;
 }


constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Por favor me pueden dar una ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

La forma más fácil de hacer esto es utilizando servicios.

Puede generarlos directamente con angular cli  `ng generate service MiServicio`

Luego creas una variable o algún objecto de alcance público (En el servicio)

Luego en el constructor de tus componentes, haces referencia al nombre de tu servicio

```
constructor(private miServicio: MiServicio) { }
```

Ahi ya tienes tus datos accesibles desde cualquier componente en onde importas tu servicio.

Aquí está paso por paso, cualquier duda puedes hacerlo saber en los comentarios
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Este metodo lo agrague en mi servicio, pero me sale un error, no se si puedo usar eventos en los servicios fileUpload(event) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsText(event.srcElement.files[0]);
   var me = this;
   reader.onload = function () {
     me.fileText = reader.result;
     var json = me.fileText;
     me.datos = JSON.parse(json)
     me.nombre=me.datos;
   }
 }

Comment: y este es mi evento para la cargar del archivo <span class="done">
  <button mat-fab color="primary">
      <label  mat-list-avatar >
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
            <input id="file-upload" type="file" accept=".json" (change)="fileUpload($event)" [style.display]="'none'">
      </label>
  </button>
</span>.

Comment: UploadComponent.html:47 ERROR TypeError: _co.fileUpload is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UploadComponent.html:47)
    at handleEvent (core.js:9953)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11046)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:10749)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7415)
    at core.js:7859
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:1140)
    atZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3662)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/